# Проблема с путями в .sh

Tags: linux, bash

Есть очень просто .sh скрипт

```
source env/bin/activate && python src/main.py "$@" && deactivate
```

Так вот проблема в чем, мне нужно чтобы пути в нем оставались локальными, но рабочая директория не менялась.
Например:

```
[qwerty /]$ sh /some/path/starter.sh --get-cwd

/
...выполнение питоновской проги...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что именно нужно. Но возможно вот такой вариант поможет

```
SCRIPT_FILE=`readlink -e $0`
SCRIPT_DIR=`dirname $SCRIPT_FILE`
```

В результате этого в переменной **$SCRIPT_DIR** будет полный путь до директории где лежит этот bash скрипт. И так понимаю в вашем случае запуск скрипта на питоне будет вот таким образом

```
python $SCRIPT_DIR/src/main.py "$@"
```